# how to fix SimpleObstacleShadowing error "No obstacles have been added -- in module (Veins::ObstacleControl)"

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to simulate a simple scenario in veins when launchd the simulation work for a moment then i have the following error :

```
Unable to use SimpleObstacleShadowing: No obstacles have been added --     in module (Veins::ObstacleControl) myNet.obstacles (id=2), at t=2.90795546076s, event #103
```

SimpleObstacleShadowing model in config.xml file :

```
<AnalogueModel type="SimpleObstacleShadowing">
<parameter name="carrierFrequency" type="double" value="5.890e+9"/> 
 <obstacles>
  <type id="building" db-per-cut="9" db-per-meter="0.4" />
 </obstacles>
</AnalogueModel>
```

omnetpp.ini file :

```
[General]
network = myapp.myNet
debug-on-errors = true
print-undisposed = true
sim-time-limit = 200s
**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true
myNet.playgroundSizeX = 2000 m
myNet.playgroundSizeY = 2000 m
myNet.playgroundSizeZ = 30 m
myNet.annotations.draw = true
myNet.connecionManager.coreDebug = true
myNet.connecionManager.sendDirect = true
myNet.connecionManager.maxInterfDist = 1000m
myNet.connecionManager.drawMaxIntfDist = true 
myNet.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("hello.launchd.xml")
*.obstacles.debug = false
*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("helloConfig.xml",       "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")
myNet.node[*].applType = "TraCIDemo11p"
myNet.rsu.applType = "TraCIDemoRSU11p"
myNet.rsu.mobility.x = 200
myNet.rsu.mobility.y = 200
myNet.rsu.mobility.z = 0
myNet.node[*].veinsmobility.x = 0
myNet.node[*].veinsmobility.y = 0
myNet.node[*].veinsmobility.z = 1.895
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.usePropagationDelay = true
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true 
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.analogueModels = xmldoc("helloConfig.xml")
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.decider =  xmldoc("helloConfig.xml")
myNet.*.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
myNet.*.nic.mac1609_4.txPower = 20mW
```

Comment: Is your simulation supposed to contain geometry (such as buildings) that block radio waves? If it is not, remove the instantiation of <AnalogueModel type="SimpleObstacleShadowing"> in your config.xml. If it is, some configuration error caused the model to not load any radio obstacles (which is why it is complaining)

Comment: @Christoph Sommer yes i have to use obstacleShadowing module, i will verify my omnetpp.ini file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any obstacles in your scenario. Try to remove the lines

```
*.obstacles.debug = false
*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("helloConfig.xml",       "//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")
```

and run the simulation again.
The syntax to create polygons can be found in the [user documentation](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/userdoc/Simulation/Shapes.html).

According to your setup of the config.xml, you have to set the `type` of your polygons to `building`

Comment: I have to use this module I can't remove these lines .how do I can add obstacles in my scenario?